# Zero power zero and $L^0$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

What is $0^0$?

It is said to be undefined.
I come from a linear algebra background (so very less calculus exposure).

$L^0$ norm is defined as:
$$
L^p = (\sum_i|x_i|^p)^{(1/p)}
$$
with $p=0$.
Now this is argued to count the number nonzero elements in a vector $\textbf{x}$. If this is taken to be true, then the summation should be $1$ for any $x\neq0$ , which is true, but also $0^0$ should be $0$, which seems contradictory to arguments in calculus.

Source: https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10005.3-5.shtml

Thanks.

Comment: This definition of the "0-norm" isn't very useful because (1) it doesn't satisfy the properties of a norm and (2) $0^{0}$ is conventionally defined to be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is useful to say $0^0$ is undefined.  Sometimes it is useful to say $0^0 = 1$.  And (as you note) sometimes it is useful to say $0^0 = 0$.

In the case of the $l^0$ "norm", as you note we should take $0^0=0$.  A more complete definition would be
$$
\lim_{p \to 0+} \left(\sum_i |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p}
$$
which does not require defining $0^0$.

For a beginning student, with no background in calculus and limits, a textbook just has to do the best it can...